# Why is my C code producing wrong results?

Tags: c

When I run my code and enter an age which is outside 13 and 19, it still says "You are a teenager"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int age;

    printf("Enter age: \n");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if(age<13 && age>19) {
        printf("You are not a teenager\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("You are a teenager\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is supposed to output "You are not a teenager".

Comment: `if(age<13 && age>19)` should be `if(age<13 || age>19)`. A number can't be less than `13` and greater than `19` at the same time. Therefore, ``if(age<13 && age>19)` will always evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Make a habit of "reading your code in English". This says "if age is less than 13 and age is greater than 19". That doesn't make any sense in basic boolean math, how can a number be less than 13 but greater than 19.

Comment: There is no need to downvote a beginner question that was clearly asked, shown attempts and so on (although the title isn't perfect)

Comment: @Cid But arguably this isn't even a programming question, but fundamental math.

Comment: `if` I am younger than 13 `and` older than 65 `then` I will get both child allowance and a pension.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but boolean arithmetic and programming are pretty close

Comment: @Cid There's a reason that good universities let you chew through them boring boolean algebra/discrete math classes before you are allowed to take the beginner programming class though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code

```
if(age<13 && age>19)
```

is a condition that can never be TRUE. No number can be simultaneously less than 13 **and** greater than 19.

What you need is

```
if(age >= 13 && age <= 19) 
{
    //teenager
}
else
   // not teenager
```

Comment: You don't mind my cheeky edit? (So I can upvote in clear conscience.)

Comment: Just guardin' you from the theoretical physicists.

Comment: May I also suggest `if ( 13 <= age  &&  age <= 19 ) {...}`? Some find it more readable.

Comment: Fixed the language a little bit